Is there a way to call a ResponseEntity<> api from Android app?
I want to call my server written with SpringBoot 3 framework that exposes an API like this:
public ResponseEntity<List<PostDTO>> getPosts()
and I want to call it from my AndroidStudio java app.
I tried calling it with Retrofit2 client with this implementation implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.11.0' and in my app's PostService.java I tried something like this
@GET("v1/profiles/gigio/posts")
Response<List<Post>> getPosts();

and like this also
@GET("v1/profiles/gigio/posts")
Call<List<Post>> getPosts();

but when I actually call it like here:
// retrieve posts for home page from server
postService = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(PostService.class);
Call<List<Post>> call = postService.getPosts();

in calling getPosts I get a very long error, the end of which looks like this:
2024-08-05 20:01:23.621 29123-29123 example.app         com.example.app                  A  runtime.cc:699] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: the return type of CallObjectMethodA does not match retrofit2.Response com.example.app.service.PostService.getPosts()
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:699]     in call to CallObjectMethodA
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:699]     from void com.example.app.fragment.community.CommunityFragment.onViewCreated(android.view.View, android.os.Bundle)
2024-08-05 20:01:35.276 29123-29123 libc                    com.example.app                  A  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 29123 (example.app), pid 29123 (example.app)

Post and PostDTO have the same fields so I think the problem is the ResponseEntity but I would prefer a client-side solution rather than changing the server.
So is there a way to resolve this client-side? To handle the ResponseEntity returned from the server?

The main problem here is that your server returns a ResponseEntity<List<PostDTO>>, but your Retrofit interface is trying to parse it directly into List<Post> or Response<List<Post>>. We need to adjust your Retrofit interface to properly handle the ResponseEntity.
Here's a suggested solution:

First, create a wrapper class to represent the ResponseEntity:

public class ResponseWrapper<T> {
    private T body;
    private int statusCode;
    private Map<String, List<String>> headers;

    // Getters and setters
}


Update your PostService interface:

public interface PostService {
    @GET("v1/profiles/gigio/posts")
    Call<ResponseWrapper<List<Post>>> getPosts();
}


When calling the service, use this wrapper:

postService = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(PostService.class);
Call<ResponseWrapper<List<Post>>> call = postService.getPosts();

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseWrapper<List<Post>>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseWrapper<List<Post>>> call, Response<ResponseWrapper<List<Post>>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            ResponseWrapper<List<Post>> wrapper = response.body();
            if (wrapper != null) {
                List<Post> posts = wrapper.getBody();
                // Process your posts here
            }
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseWrapper<List<Post>>> call, Throwable t) {
        // Handle failure
    }
});


You might need to create a custom Gson converter to properly deserialize the ResponseEntity. Here's a basic example:

public class ResponseEntityConverter implements Converter<ResponseBody, ResponseWrapper<?>> {
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public ResponseWrapper<?> convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        String json = value.string();
        Type type = new TypeToken<ResponseWrapper<?>>(){}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
}


When creating your Retrofit instance, add this converter:

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(YOUR_BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(new ResponseEntityConverterFactory())
    .build();

Where ResponseEntityConverterFactory is a custom Converter.Factory that uses the ResponseEntityConverter.
This approach should allow you to handle the ResponseEntity on the client side without changing the server. It creates a wrapper class that mimics the structure of ResponseEntity, allowing Retrofit to properly parse the response.
Remember to adjust the Post class to match the fields in PostDTO if they're not exactly the same. If there are differences, you might need to create a custom Gson TypeAdapter to handle the conversion.

I tried both with .addConverterFactory(new ResponseEntityConverterFactory()) and without, still get the same error. Double checked that DTOs are the same. Am I doing anything wrong?

Sorry can't help further. Try asking ChatGPT or Claude
